# Substitution for egg YOLK in cake recipe?

Tags: baking, substitutions, eggs, cake, baking-powder

I'm making a cake for a person with an egg allergy. I typically just use Bob Red Mill egg replacer, but the baking powder in the replacer causes the cake to come out flat and overly tender. This is the recipe I'm using

- 3 large egg yolks
- 1/2 cup heavy cream
- 3/4 teaspoon vanilla
- 1 1/2 cups cake flour
- 3/4 cup sugar
- 1 1/4 teaspoons baking powder
- 1/4 teaspoon salt
- 10 1/2 teaspoons unsalted butter, room temperature

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless you’re trying to recreate a specific cake recipe (family recipe, something from their childhood, etc), it’s often easier to just find another recipe online.  Searching file ‘vegan cake recipe’ or ‘eggless cake recipe’ works rather well these days